# How can I login with OAuth2.0 in DevOps API in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I tried many API Calls with Postman and It works fine but I only get it to work with PAT.

Below you can find my API Call with my PAT. How can I change it to OAuth2.0?

By the way, I'm using the DataVerse API with OAuth2.0 but rewrite doesnt work.

**EDIT:**

I used the OAuthWebSample but there is another Error:
When I click on "Authorize" it says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

What I need to do to get it to work is to copy the website-url given in the publish section in visual studio and switch it.

So I got PUBLISHEDNAME.azurewebsites.net instead of APPNAME.azurewebsites.net

When I'm switching the CallbackUrl in web.config to PUBLISHEDNAME.azurewebsites.net I'll get a 400.

How can I fix it?

```
    private const string URL = "DEV LINK";
string testToken = "PAT";
public TextMesh APIText;
public TextMeshProUGUI Text;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

public void GenerateDevOps()
{
    StartCoroutine(ProcessDevOps(URL));
}

public IEnumerator ProcessDevOps(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + " " + testToken);

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            Text.text = request.downloadHandler.text;
           /*  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(request.downloadHandler.text);
            var dataInhalt = data.value.ToArray();
            Debug.Log(dataInhalt);
           foreach (Value content in dataInhalt)
            {
                string name = content.firstname;
                string lastname = content.lastname;
                //textapi.text = name + " " + lastname;
                names = names + name + lastname + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            APIHeader.text = URL;
            
            m_Object.text = names;

            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops. Note that you should be using Azure DevOps Services (the cloud version) since OAuth2.0 is not supported in on-prem Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: Yep, I tried the sample but when I'm click on authorize Ill get an 404

Comment: Fixed, now I got on /oauth/callback a 404.

Comment: Hi there, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, please edit your question and give more details about the error and what you have tried so that people can investigate the question further~

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error code means that the resource doesn't exist, or the authenticated user doesn't have permission to see that it exists. So here are two troubleshooting advices:

1. Check your REST API using PAT to see whether the error is about the API.
2. Configure OAuth 2.0 exactly as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#register-your-app). In particular, make sure you have configured permissions correctly, which means that you can use the access token to read data and send it back.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now but I'll get another error written above.

Comment: @MrFabou Do you have any special permission limitations for your call back url?

Comment: I don't know how to look up those. I just created the VSTS App with Workitem Perms and copied the Callback URL.